# Separating a group of 12 people into 4 trios for hockey game

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Among the 12 people, 4 play left-side, 4 play middle and 4 play right-side. I have to divide these 12 people in 4 teams where each team needs one person of each role (left, middle, right). How many distinct ways to place the players in trio.

My answer is $C(4,1)^3 * C(3,1)^3 * C(2,1)^3 * C(1,1)^3$. Is this correct?

Comment: When you propose an answer, you should explain your reasoning since it helps users of this site detect any errors you may have made.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make four teams out of three pools of four people each.

The first pool is assigned arbitrarily, $1$ way.

The next pool is assigned in any of $4!$ ways.

The third pool is assigned in any of $4!$ ways.

The total is $(4!)^2$, or 576.

@ploosu2 pointed this out in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This answer assumes any player can play any place (left, mid or right).

The teams can be formed from an ordered line of the people (first is the left-side of the first team, second is the middle of first, and so on upto the right-side player of the fourth team). So every permutation of $12$ produces a separation and the answer is $12!$.

Notice how this can also be though like this: You first choose the $3$ players of the first team out of the $12$. But their playing positions matter, so in other words the order matters and you must multiply by $3!$. Then continue to choose the next team from the remaining $9$ etc. You get

$${ {12}\choose{3} }*3! * { {9}\choose{3} }*3! * { {6}\choose{3} }*3! * { {3}\choose{3} }*3! = 12!$$

Comment: You are treating the teams as distinct, but if it weren't would we have to divide by 4! ?

Comment: Yes, if the teams are indistinguishable, then divide by $4!$.

Comment: Actually I don't think that's right, I was seeing the problem as, let's say we have sam, dean, tim, clark that play left-side only. If we were to permutate the 12 people your suggestion would count a team where sam and dean could be together, which I don't want. I looked at the problem as, let's replace those name with L1, L2, L3, L4 and so on. We would have L1, L2, L3, L4, R1, R2, R3, R4 and M1, M2, M3, M4 as players that we need to separate into 4 groups, each needing 1 L, 1 R and 1 M. Is that more clear?

Comment: @Ok, I see, that is a more reasonable assumption (and I too actually though it should be like that in the beginning but then forgot :D). Then, if we use the original "players in line"-argument, we must have the L, M, R-players in correct positions and get that there are $(4!)^3$ configurations. And then divide by order of teams (if indistinguishablity is what we want) to get $576$. Your original answer is correct (upon a division by $4!$).